# how do you build your appliances?

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machine, appliance

virtual machines hold great promise as a way to distribute hard to configure applications. i have been using jeos vmbuilder (and some bash scripts) to generate my appliances, but i'm looking for something more elegant.

in my case, i'm looking for a solution that will build a linux-based vm with configured versions of tomcat and mysql as a base. each future release would be a new war file and a sql update script. it'd be really nice if already deployed vms could self-update and test builds could be pushed to ec2.

in my brief search, i've found [rpath rbuilder](http://www.rpath.org/ui/), [turnkey linux](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/),
[vagrant up](http://vagrantup.com/), [suse studio](http://susestudio.com/), [jeos vmbuilder](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/JeOSVMBuilder), and [vmware studio](http://www.vmware.com/appliances/getting-started/learn/vmware_studio.html). rather than try all of these, i figure i'd ask what this community uses to build and distribute appliances...

Answer (score 0):

I use [pungi](https://fedorahosted.org/pungi/) myself.